# How to do a repeated measures analysis in R?

Tags: r

I have this dataset and I am trying to fit a model that assesses whether treatment has an impact on weight (outcome) and in particular, that allows the treatment effect to vary over time. There are multiple measurements per 'id'.

I am trying to analyze the data using a repeated measures ANOVA.
The dataset contains a few variables: id (the patient’s
unique identifier), treatment (an indicator for whether the patient received the new
diet (1) or not (0)), and age (the patient’s age in years at study entry), outcome (the patient’s weight in pounds recorded at a particular visit),
and visitnumber (the visit number).

```
 > dput(full)
structure(list(id = c(965, 168, 133, 566, 145, 79, 49, 182, 998, 
476, 314, 578, 800, 712, 574, 858, 743, 260, 155, 493, 411, 397, 
232, 972, 357, 27, 794, 39, 723, 711, 982, 305, 804, 504, 607, 
146, 168, 890, 720, 170, 379, 841, 543, 825, 771, 224, 8, 739, 
876, 844, 5, 308, 997, 275, 802, 552, 683, 488, 743, 61, 439, 
687, 172, 990, 101, 979, 57, 498, 148, 694, 810, 970, 470, 442, 
321, 650, 22, 735, 622, 697, 601, 845, 689, 783, 297, 502, 901, 
902, 907, 933, 831, 848, 238, 244, 562, 238, 54, 307, 157, 833
), outcome = c(178.1292789, 152.6929382, 154.9682105, 180.1792337, 
155.5643838, 158.1777561, 141.2326605, 158.0372637, 170.7657935, 
150.0930737, 144.8978423, 167.7295463, 170.4530778, 166.2320969, 
174.6196961, 172.9699754, 165.6665897, 143.5506991, 150.8801473, 
152.8867248, 141.627696, 147.7234166, 144.2490439, 186.4303623, 
137.4472087, 150.8790336, 175.1623773, 156.37109, 177.8236086, 
170.4165886, 175.8410723, 143.3243023, 159.6941819, 180.1754229, 
163.2772414, 143.8418165, 143.5552981, 172.6175974, 177.6680813, 
137.9041874, 163.4326879, 178.2426015, 173.1707072, 176.0714329, 
165.7867407, 145.6877951, 150.2737186, 184.4544812, 158.2952331, 
182.1838354, 148.9614953, 149.8798918, 156.5142777, 163.2968075, 
177.3107927, 165.4462144, 167.9021459, 148.1217567, 163.2306892, 
145.5216289, 154.5574847, 179.0495321, 145.9386308, 181.1654107, 
144.8315221, 171.6145523, 148.5750191, 144.775874, 148.1463073, 
172.590192, 160.9216146, 174.7643147, 139.3596933, 157.1786811, 
153.3880836, 183.8471692, 148.5695133, 173.8687851, 151.5755017, 
165.0664097, 180.3950209, 164.5429984, 164.983456, 178.9630521, 
137.9087173, 168.668939, 169.8311543, 180.9404174, 174.0725322, 
173.8267465, 174.4805713, 166.6538422, 137.5949582, 152.1977455, 
166.0765327, 148.9605142, 140.4552133, 147.5073477, 146.426167, 
164.9396603), visitnumber = c(4, 3, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 5, 
2, 5, 1, 4, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 
2, 5, 1, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 1, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 5, 4, 4, 1, 
2, 5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 
2, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 1, 5, 1, 2, 
2, 4, 2, 3, 1), treatment = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0), age = c(62.56849707, 59.9875489, 58.92425704, 
62.86864989, 55.61336473, 64.98774785, 61.58430531, 66.91110054, 
60.15734064, 61.336864, 56.22408195, 57.41464728, 62.32706193, 
56.24078384, 59.9129205, 59.72669943, 60.7366701, 68.07162556, 
65.83706817, 58.34790981, 62.92541931, 60.44772228, 59.05602316, 
60.3587956, 64.20115418, 53.6724036, 63.85708009, 56.08114237, 
65.0820994, 58.23011895, 62.12986331, 61.85220756, 54.94833195, 
54.9549317, 59.08634974, 66.85477235, 59.9875489, 57.57695066, 
54.79087254, 66.9157855, 66.20755394, 59.35629854, 62.46671274, 
67.65557345, 61.17523285, 60.83744515, 55.4094255, 61.50789629, 
60.07359108, 55.77166234, 66.2290783, 56.01880637, 65.75930218, 
64.63645494, 59.35355296, 62.6060523, 70.28167557, 52.91174325, 
60.7366701, 57.8139364, 58.41752334, 56.53555588, 58.75351312, 
60.74961013, 61.51029989, 54.9842095, 56.00229494, 64.40211717, 
54.86495493, 66.54053274, 53.74773261, 62.06325335, 59.65814464, 
59.07963141, 59.17691183, 53.61106941, 62.58076922, 67.01218874, 
54.08783732, 61.38234868, 61.70638178, 61.59147749, 62.97231388, 
64.1034271, 53.7801112, 62.22005378, 61.43731322, 60.49405197, 
62.2994082, 56.56848077, 59.85286766, 61.65844302, 59.36361724, 
61.53807386, 62.97919029, 59.36361724, 61.85642462, 59.21186756, 
56.24220335, 61.16389981)), row.names = c(4336L, 750L, 596L, 
2524L, 648L, 353L, 211L, 811L, 4487L, 2132L, 1409L, 2577L, 3587L, 
3184L, 2559L, 3854L, 3325L, 1158L, 691L, 2204L, 1842L, 1781L, 
1032L, 4368L, 1602L, 117L, 3558L, 169L, 3237L, 3182L, 4411L, 
1366L, 3602L, 2256L, 2708L, 656L, 752L, 3997L, 3224L, 760L, 1699L, 
3779L, 2427L, 3700L, 3452L, 999L, 35L, 3309L, 3930L, 3794L, 22L, 
1382L, 4481L, 1228L, 3596L, 2466L, 3051L, 2184L, 3324L, 268L, 
1966L, 3073L, 769L, 4450L, 454L, 4396L, 251L, 2227L, 661L, 3104L, 
3629L, 4359L, 2105L, 1978L, 1440L, 2905L, 96L, 3289L, 2774L, 
3119L, 2682L, 3796L, 3080L, 3509L, 1330L, 2244L, 4045L, 4049L, 
4070L, 4190L, 3732L, 3808L, 1063L, 1088L, 2504L, 1060L, 235L, 
1375L, 700L, 3739L), class = "data.frame")
```

I did `model <- aov(outcome~factor(treatment)+Error(factor(id)), data = new)` but not sure this is correct.
Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you for providing your data but in your sample data, all of your `treatment` values are `1` so the model will not run. Try changing the reproducible data to randomly sample 100 rows from the full data by using `dput(full_data[sample(full_data$id, 100),])

Comment: Thank you @jpsmith. I have updated the description so that it now includes a random sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a one way repeated measures ANOVA model as follows, assuming that `visitnumber` is the only within-subject factor, to examine whether treatment has an effect on the weight outcome across the five visits (I defined  sample data as `df`):

```
rm_model <- aov(outcome ~ treatment + age + Error(id/visitnumber), data = df)
summary(rm_model)

# > summary(rm_model)
# 
# Error: id
# Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
# treatment  1  11053   11053
# 
# Error: id:visitnumber
# Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
# treatment  1  813.4   813.4
# 
# Error: Within
# Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
# treatment  1   2759  2759.4   64.97 2.24e-12 ***
#   age        1     21    21.2    0.50    0.481    
# Residuals 95   4035    42.5                     
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a mixed effects model using `lme4()`. You would include random intercepts for `id`, and can include a `treatment` by `visitnumber` interaction to allow the effect of `treatment` to vary over time.

```r
library(lme4)
library(sjPlot)

model_linear <- lmer(
  outcome ~ treatment * visitnumber + (1 | id),  # random intercepts for id
  data = mydata
)

summary(model_linear)

#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: outcome ~ treatment * visitnumber + (1 | id)
#>    Data: mydata
#> 
#> REML criterion at convergence: 607.8
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
#> -0.85534 -0.11282  0.00127  0.12433  0.95700 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
#>  id       (Intercept) 28.9641  5.3818  
#>  Residual              0.7958  0.8921  
#> Number of obs: 100, groups:  id, 97
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>                       Estimate Std. Error t value
#> (Intercept)           162.3155     1.5297 106.111
#> treatment              -2.4956     1.9717  -1.266
#> visitnumber             3.2594     0.4517   7.216
#> treatment:visitnumber  -7.0199     0.5466 -12.844
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>             (Intr) trtmnt vstnmb
#> treatment   -0.776              
#> visitnumber -0.872  0.676       
#> trtmnt:vstn  0.721 -0.826 -0.826

plot_model(model_linear, terms = c("visitnumber", "treatment"), type = "pred")
```

[image]

```r
# add quadratic term for time
model_quadratic <- lmer(
  outcome ~ treatment * poly(visitnumber, 2) + (1 | id), 
  data = mydata
)

summary(model_quadratic)

#> Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
#> Formula: outcome ~ treatment * poly(visitnumber, 2) + (1 | id)
#>    Data: mydata
#> 
#> REML criterion at convergence: 582.7
#> 
#> Scaled residuals: 
#>        Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
#> -2.140e-03 -2.970e-04  7.930e-06  3.135e-04  2.350e-03 
#> 
#> Random effects:
#>  Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev.
#>  id       (Intercept) 2.985e+01 5.463718
#>  Residual             4.837e-06 0.002199
#> Number of obs: 100, groups:  id, 97
#> 
#> Fixed effects:
#>                                 Estimate Std. Error t value
#> (Intercept)                     171.9800     0.7511 228.961
#> treatment                       -23.7468     1.1147 -21.302
#> poly(visitnumber, 2)1            46.1923     6.6151   6.983
#> poly(visitnumber, 2)2             4.0663     2.4504   1.659
#> treatment:poly(visitnumber, 2)1 -90.0634     6.6152 -13.615
#> treatment:poly(visitnumber, 2)2 -16.7434     2.4506  -6.832
#> 
#> Correlation of Fixed Effects:
#>             (Intr) trtmnt p(,2)1 p(,2)2 t:(,2)1
#> treatment   -0.674                             
#> ply(vst,2)1 -0.041  0.028                      
#> ply(vst,2)2 -0.041  0.028  1.000               
#> trtmn:(,2)1  0.041 -0.028 -1.000 -1.000        
#> trtmn:(,2)2  0.041 -0.028 -1.000 -1.000  1.000

plot_model(model_quadratic, terms = c("visitnumber", "treatment"), type = "pred")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>